Is it possible to query an Amazon RDS instance directly from Step function?
I have some step function that in case of failure, I want to update a rds record (generally run an sql query) in Aurora serverless data base in the same aws account.
Is it possible? Or should I create lambda that will do the update?
Thanks :)

You will need the Step Function to call an AWS Lambda function. You will then need to code the Lambda function to perform the update.
